# WinJS DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL

Tags: javascript, image, winjs

I am trying to save images for an Application to the localFolder with the help of the Winjs.xhr function. This works totally fine, but if I want to put the picture to the src attribute of an image I always get Error DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL ms-appdata:///local/name.png. I tried it with different images but this error always occures.

Javascript:

```
var imgUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com/windows/Framework/images/win_logo.png";

WinJS.xhr({
    url: imgUrl,
    responseType: "blob"
}).then(
    function completed(result) {
        var newFile = result.response;

        var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;

        var fileName = "image.png";
        var CreationCollisionOption = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption;

        return localFolder.createFileAsync(fileName,CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting);

}).then(
    function createFileSuccess() {
        var msgtext = "File downloaded successfully!";
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msgtext);
        return msg.showAsync();
});
```

HTML:

`<img src="ms-appdata:///local/image.png"/>`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I saw other people also having "the unable to decode" error on Internet Explorer. There the problem seemed to be using very large images. But im only working with icon-sized images, so it seems to be a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6352bce1-1427-47ec-9dab-dc41cda165c4/winjswinjs-dom7009-unable-to-decode-image-at-url?forum=wpdevelop#6352bce1-1427-47ec-9dab-dc41cda165c4

I opened the file, but wrote nothing in it.